# Wubi to install Xubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, wubi

Is there any wubi that can install xubuntu 13.10?I have the wubi to install 13.10 but is there any wubi to install xubuntu 13.10?

I hope this question has an answer that could help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu hasn't been available with Wubi since release 12.10. The lead Xubuntu developer, Pasi Lallinaho, requested that it be removed ([reference](http://ubuntu.5.x6.nabble.com/WUBI-tp5020237p5020238.html)):

> There has been discussion about this on the mailing list and on
>   #xubuntu-devel before, but the short answer is that there wasn't enough testers and it was only more workload for the team to support
>   that.

It's still available on the [12.04 Wubi](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/)

There is a way to trick Wubi into installing Xubuntu, if you don't mind a bit of work. This is not recommended, but I did it and wrote up the Howto here: http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2012/10/tricking-wubi-installing-xubuntu.html

Comment: Does this only work for 12.10 or also work for xubuntu 13.10?

Comment: @user220674 It works for any release.